# How to set a label centered behind a "range" slider with css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I got a problem with my css. If I want a label to overlap a div I just set both position:absolute and top: 0px , left: 0px. That works normally for me, but in the following case I have no idea how to set my text above the slider or under a transparent slider. I hope you can help me with this problem.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>
                <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider1" step="5" />
                <p id="rowlabel1">Test</p>
            </h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#rowlabel1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#slider1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rHFS5/

Comment: Just asking: why not use a `label` if you need a label? Accessibility and some extra UI functionality.

Comment: Mhm thats a good question.. but i dont think that it would solve my problem or? But I will try it thx :)

Comment: It will not solve your problem. Your problem is that you use some scripts (jQuery Mobile) that modify your DOM and possibly even your CSS. Analyze the live DOM in the inspector and write CSS for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it. I've changed the html a bit, but the essence is the same.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #rowlabel1 {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #slider1 {
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .label {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .framer {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="framer">
         <h3>
            <div class="label">
                <span id="rowlabel1">Test</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider1" step="5" />
            </div>
         </h3>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

HTH